# Was there a trinity in Eru?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

Being that Tolkien was a Catholic, I wouldn't be surprised if he made Eru three different people, but I can't think of any references to it.  If so, who are the three persons?

Comment: None come to mind to me either. Given Tolkein's hatred of allegory, I wouldn't be shocked if he avoided such an obvious parallel to the Christian God.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to the other question to include the "Son" element, as it seems reasonable to have all the info in one place.

Answer (score 0):

i would say no, as "In Tolkien's invented Elvish language Quenya, Eru means "The One", or "He that is Alone"[1]" -wikepedia(lol). i would hazard to guess that if eru was 3 parts Tolkien would have put that into his name (since he created the name/language) beyond this there is no more references that i could find, he does have maybe a "holy spirit" reference in the flame imperishable, but that also could just simple be more a reference as the spirit that resides in all people aka similar to the human soul.

Comment: The Christian God is also one and only. It's not a contradiction (according to Christianity). Eru's threefold nature is IMO well confirmed. Other than the "Holy Spirit", through his characters Tolkien also discussed how Eru would one day enter into Arda (in a way unknown to the characters who couldn't picture the designer getting into his picture) and heal all the Marring from beginning to the end. And that is obviously the Incarnation of the Son - http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Athrabeth_Finrod_ah_Andreth